# Splitting data, indexing and querying

Tags: solr, solr4

I have a table in the DB with 2 columns, `id` and `detail`.

The `id` column has unique ids and the `detail` column has data like below -

1. A 20% B 30% C 50%
2. B 50% D 50%
3. X 10% A 40% Z 50%

I can do nothing about the way it is in the DB.

I want to let my users search using the following queries -

1. A < 20. - meaning all documents where A is less than 20%.
2. B > 30, X > 5%. - meaning all documents where B is greater than 30 and X is greater than 5.

I am unable to figure out the combination of tokenizer, filter to get this going.

What I have done is found the total number of unique types (A, B, C, ...), created those many fields in the Solr schema which are `typeCode1` for `A`, `typeCode2` for `B`, etc and the corresponding values which are `typeValue1`, `typeValue2`, etc. If `A` is not available for a document then the `typeCode1` is `null` and so is it's `typeValue1` field. I also have a mapping table in the DB where I look for which type is entered by the user and then get the corresponding field that is in Solr and then search.

**EDIT - Adding a few more details**

The data from the DB is fetched. Let us say it is `A 20% D 30% C 50%`.

Then I split on the basis of `%<space>` (`String.split("")`). So I have 3 rows in my array.

Then I check the mapping of the type in the DB to find out which Solr field name corresponds to which type.

Once I have the field then I submit `A` to `typeCode1` and `20` to `typeValue1`, `D` to `typeCode4` and `30` to `typeValue4` and so on.

Currently the total number of unique types I have is 45, however, it can increase and my current approach is not scalable.

Comment: How are you indexing content? Are you planning on transforming it in SQL, or do you submit documents to Solr through JSON/XML? How many different fieldnames are possible for the detail column? Are there only integer values? How many documents are we talking in total-ish?

Comment: @MatsLindh - Added some more details to the question. I submit the documents using solrj. There are about 45 unique types (so far), the values are integers. Total documents that I have currently is 37000+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to add a dynamic field for each typeCode, such as `A_code` with `20` as the value. That will allow you to use the field as you'd use any field in Solr, and query it using intervals, above/under, do faceting on the field etc.

```
<dynamicField name="*_code" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

The only "real" downside is that your cache size will grow, since you'll get one internal cache per field. This cache will be sized according to the total number of documents in the index. For a small index like the one you describe and with only 45 different field names that shouldn't be an issue.